# Audio event still firing off event after removed via removeEventListener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, html5-audio

I've got the following two lifecycle methods in my React component, which is an audio track that contains an HTML `<audio>` element:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const {track} = this.props;

  this.refs.audio.src = track.getTrackUrl();
  _.each(this.audioEvents, (callback, eventName) => {
    this.refs.audio.addEventListener(eventName, callback.bind(this));
  });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  _.each(this.audioEvents, (callback, eventName) => {
    console.info(`Removed ${eventName} from ${this.props.track.name}`);
    this.refs.audio.removeEventListener(eventName, callback.bind(this));
  });
}
```

I can see from the `console.info` call that all the events are being removed, yet I still get the following error when navigating off this particular route/page:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined component.

This is happening because the `pause` callback is still getting fired off even after I've supposedly removed all event handlers:

```
pause() {
  console.log('pause got fired for', this.props.track.name);
  this.setState({playing: false});
},
```

What am I missing? I'm trying to do a nice clean-up when the component unmounts, but for some reason when I navigate off the page (causing the audio to stop playing), my event handler for `pause` still fires off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `.bind` you create a new instance of the function. So when you do this:

```
this.refs.audio.addEventListener(eventName, callback.bind(this));
```

You will no longer be able to remove that event listener because you didn't hold on to the reference to `callback.bind(this)`. Here's how you fix it.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const {track} = this.props;
  this.refs.audio.src = track.getTrackUrl();
  this.boundAudioEvents = _.mapValues(this.audioEvents, (callback, eventName) => {
    const boundEvent = callback.bind(this)
    this.refs.audio.addEventListener(eventName, boundEvent);
    return boundEvent;
  });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  _.each(this.boundAudioEvents, (callback, eventName) => {
    console.info(`Removed ${eventName} from ${this.props.track.name}`);
    this.refs.audio.removeEventListener(eventName, callback);
  });
}
```

Comment: Awesome stuff! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this, been battling with this for hours.